# clan war defense under construction

Tags: clash-of-clans

If my archer tower is at level 6 and is under construction before we go into a clan war and it won't be completed until after the war, will it be inactive during the war?

Answer (score 6):

No. The archer tower will be functioning during the war. It will still remain at level 6 though, unlike newly constructed buildings, which finish to level 1 on your clan war base if they have not finished yet.

Comment: i can confirm this too. /+1