# Will Level 1 buildings under construction be active in the War Base?

Tags: clash-of-clans

I know that when we are upgrading any buildings to Nth level it will be the N-1 level in war base . I recently upgraded my town hall and started to build the new defenses, but these will not be completed within the preparation time. But when I edit my war base I can see the fully built defenses.

So on war day will the defenses be active or will it leave a blind spot (holes in between buildings so that enemy can deploy troops)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [clan war defense under construction](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/196537/clan-war-defense-under-construction)

Comment: @aytimothy I clearly stated in my question that I know if its at level N, defense towers will work at previous levels. There was no information about new defense structures, which is what this question is about ...

Comment: It's not your question that I was marking as duplicate - It was the answer. (Although to say it's not as well-written as mine)

Comment: Seeing as how the answer on this question is much, much better than the proposed duplicate, I would advocate keeping this one, and closing that one as a duplicate of this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

All defensive towers are active in your war base, even if:

1. They're still being built (Level 0 to 1)
2. Being upgraded (they'll be at the level before the upgrade start)
3. Out of ammo (ie. X-Bows)

Answering your query about newly built towers that haven't been completed yet:
**They'll function as normal, they'll be physically there (not leave any gaps) except only as Level 1.**
*I mean c'mon... Who's seen a Level 0 building?*

**Note:** *This only applies to newly built buildings... Or at least those that are under construction.*
Cancellation of its construction will remove the building from your War base.

Comment: Umm my query was whether it would leave behind gaps or not specifically. Any reference to supercell wiki for your answer ?

Comment: The [wiki](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Wars_FAQ#How_is_my_war_base_different_from_my_village.3F) doesn't cover anything about buildings that are under construction (brand new). I'm citing from experience.

Comment: ok. I have one mortar and wizard tower under construction. Will see in todays war.

Comment: Just don't worry; it'll be there.

Comment: Edit: ... Unless you cancelled construction...

Comment: Sweet it worked.

Comment: can confirm this answer.

Answer (score 1):

For upgrades, if the upgrade will finish before war ends, your upgraded level will show up in war base.

Comment: You should probably clarify this.  Does the upgraded level appear at the beginning?  Or does it only appear once the upgrade is complete?

Comment: Nop this is not true. I had three defenses under construction. Mortar and wizrd were new, and it appeared. Air defense level 2 was under progress but even after completion it was still at level 1